# Modify the init_wfst () function and the complete_wfst () function (python)

Tags: python

Modify the init_wfst () function and the complete_wfst () function to store non-terminal character sets in each WFST cell instead of one non-terminal one. How to do that with this code:
`

```
def init_wfst(tokens, grammar):
    numtokens = len(tokens)
    wfst = [[None for i in range(numtokens + 1)] for j in range(numtokens+1)]
    for i in range(numtokens):
        productions = grammar.productions(rhs=tokens[i])
        wfst[i][i+1] = productions[0].lhs()
    return wfst


def complete_wfst(wfst, tokens, grammar, trace=True):
    index = dict((p.rhs(), p.lhs()) for p in grammar.productions())
    numtokens = len(tokens)
    for span in range(2, numtokens + 1):
        for start in range(numtokens + 1 - span):
            end = start + span
            for mid in range(start + 1, end):
                nt1, nt2 = wfst[start][mid], wfst[mid][end]
                if nt1 and nt2 and (nt1, nt2) in index:
                    wfst[start][end] = index[(nt1, nt2)]
                    if trace:
                        print("[%s] %3s [%s] %3s [%s] ==> [%s] %3s [%s]" %
                              (start, nt1, mid, nt2, end, start, index[(nt1, nt2)], end))
    return wfst


def display(wfst, tokens):
    print('\nWFST ' + ' '.join(("%-4d" % i) for i in range(1, len(wfst))))
    for i in range(len(wfst) - 1):
        print("%d   " % i, end=" ")
        for j in range(1, len(wfst)):
            print("%-4s" % (wfst[i][j] or '.'), end=" ")
        print()


tokens = "I shot an elephant in my pajamas".split()
wfst0 = init_wfst(tokens, groucho_grammar)
display(wfst0, tokens)

wfst1 = complete_wfst(wfst0, tokens, groucho_grammar)
display(wfst1, tokens)
```

`